# Page inside custom post type (url rewrite?)

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, site-url

I am trying to create a page that I can use inside of a custom post type.

I have a CPT named forums, so the url is: example.com/forums

I would like to have a page called new-topic with the url: example.com/forums/new-topic

I have been looking at parent/child relationships and url rewrites but I am completely lost.

Comment: How are you registering your custom post type? As long as you set it up to have an archive, `example.com/forums` should be the CPT Archive - which links out to individual `forums` - and `example.com/forums/new-topic` should already be displaying an individual `forum` called `new-topic`. It does not sound like you need any sort of hierarchy, unless a `forum` should be able to contain `sub-forums`.

Comment: I think you are right and I'm not thinking about the approach correctly. Thanks for the input, I will test it and if it works you should post it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **WebElaine** for pointing out the obvious solution!

Just created a post in the custom post type and gave it a unique template, thus achieving the desired url.